# expected primary-expression before '[' token

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function which generates a Color-Code without doubles. My attempt:

```
        int random(int lowerbounds, int upperbounds)
        {
            return lowerbounds + rand() % (upperbounds - lowerbounds + 1);
        }

        enum Farbe { Red, Orange, Grey, Blue, Grey, White, Purple };
        bool err;
        int zahl;
        Farbe Code[];
        while(err)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                zahl = 0;
                zahl = random(1, 7);
                switch (zahl) {
                case 1:
                    Code[i] = Red;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Code[i] = Orange;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Code[i] = Grey;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Code[i] = Blue;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Code[i] = Green;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Code[i] = White;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Code[i] = Purple;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if(i != j)
                    {
                        if(Farbe[i] == Farbe[j]) // here is the Error
                        {
                            err = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

But the compiler always returns the error

```
...cpp:72: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
```

and

```
...cpp:72: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

I think it's a pretty simple algorithm, but I have no idea for solve.
Any help?

Comment: did you mean `Code` instead of `Farbe` on the line that causes the error ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Ohh, I'm blind: Would you post a answer so a I can accept it.

Comment: Did you not get an error on the line `Farbe Code[];`? And on the duplicate `Grey` in the declaration of `enum Farbe`? Please compile your code before you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Farbe[i] == Farbe[j]) // here is the Error
{
err = true;
}
```

Farbe is an enum type, not an array variable.
You must be referring to the vriable `code` of type Farbe

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you used `Farbe` instead of `Code` in the line that generates the error. It should read :

```
if(Code[i] == Code[j])
```